# Cannot convert homeScreen to UIViewController all of the sudden. Worked about 5 minutes ago

Tags: xamarin.ios

The following line of code is giving me an error:
this.rootNavigationController.PushViewController(homeScreen, false);

Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`TravelPoC.HomeScreen' expression to type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController' (CS1503) (TravelPoC)

This is happening in the FinishedLaunching method in AppDelegate.

Nothing has changed and this used to work fine.  I just try to build and get this error now and have become completely F'd.

I removed a few buttons from homeScreen in Xcode Builder, but that's it.  Just the UI elements were removed along with the associated outlets which are no longer referenced in my code.

I am confused and I am not sure where to look for the problem.  Ideas?

Am I missing something or is MonoTouch acting up?  The designer file has updated itself properly and looks fine as well as my homeScreen.cs file is fine with no errors in it to prevent it from compiling.  It also is still inheriting UIViewController

2 hours trying to figure this out and no luck.  I even reverted to an older version of the HomeScreen.xib file and it didn't fix the problem.  What the hell?  I want to cry.

Comment: Figured it out.  Somehow Build action for HomeScreen.cs got changed to Content.  I changed it back to Compile.  I feel like a grandiose douche right about now...

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thank you! I was stuck on this for so long. This is all I found on Google after like an hour of messing around, trying to figure out wtf was wrong.