# Cannot convert HomeScreen expression to type MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get my homescreen to work, but I'm getting the following error while trying to debug:

`Cannot convert 'projectI.HomeScreen' expression to type 'MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController' (CS1503)`

I looked at a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459586/cannot-convert-homescreen-to-uiviewcontroller-all-of-the-sudden-worked-about-5), but that didn't work for me. Google searches didn't quite help either.

I tried to recreate the project, but the same error occured when I tried debugging it.

The error occurs on my AppDelegate.cs file which looks like the following:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        this.window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // Create a new root view controller
        UINavigationController rootNavController = new UINavigationController ();

        // Set the homescreen
        HomeScreen homeScreen = new HomeScreen ();
        rootNavController.PushViewController (homeScreen, false);

        // make the window visible
        this.window.RootViewController = rootNavController;
        this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

`rootNavController.PushViewController (homeScreen, false);`

HomeScreen.cs looks like this:

```
public partial class HomeScreen : UIViewController
{
    public HomeScreen () : base ("HomeScreen", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

I have no clue why it's doing this, it worked perfectly when I followed the guides of Xamarin.

Any help or lead is much appreciated.

Comment: Is HomeScreen code-only, or does it also have a XIB (Interface Builder) file that goes with it?

Comment: There is a XIB file along with it. The interface is indeed made with the XCode Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked around on the Xamarin forums aswell and they suggested me to retry to delete the ViewController and remake it because likely the cause is that it didn't create a .h file.

After doing that, I launched the debugger using the simulator and now it works.

The cause was that it didn't create a .h file when I opened the .xib file in Xcode.

The solution was given me [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6474/cannot-convert-homescreen-expression-to-type-monotouch-uikit-uiviewcontroller?new=1)

For anyone else that comes across this issue, I hope this helps for you aswell.